# Django validator not triggering on file upload

Tags: python, django

I have wrote a Django app for the user to upload files and see a list of uploaded files. I want to restrict the uploads to only using gif format and wrote a simple validator. Then I pass that validator in the Model, however it never triggers and the file is saved regardless of the format. Here's what I got so far.

**views.py**

```
def list(request):
# Handle file upload
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
        newdoc.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Saved")

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
else:
    form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.all()

# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render(
    request,
    'list.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form}
)
```

**checkformat.py**

```
def validate_file_type(upload):
if not (upload.name[-4:] == '.gif'):
    raise ValidationError('File type not supported.')
```

**models.py**

```
from .checkformat import validate_file_type

def content_file_name(instance, filename):
     return '/'.join(['documents', str(filename), filename])

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, validators=[validate_file_type], null=False, verbose_name="File")
```

**forms.py**

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
docfile = forms.FileField(
    label='Select a file', widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'image/gif'})
)
```

Is there something I'm missing? I've just started learning Django. Also, I know this is not a sercure way to check for a file type, but I just want to see it work to continue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: not much wrong. Try `upload.name.lower.endswith('.gif')` though [-4:] is indeed the same but the lower might make  a difference.

Comment: Please show the code of DocumentForm.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added the DocumentForm code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
        if not '.gif' in newdoc.name:
            raise ValidationError('File type not supported.')
        else:
            newdoc.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Saved")
```

try this simple solution, hope it works as you need

Comment: Well, I changed the code and added a print after the function starts, but it does not appear in console. Maybe the call is wrong? The `checkformat.py` is located on the same level as the `models.py`, `views.py`, etc.

Comment: do once thing add this validation in the views file before the form.save and check if it works

Comment: Yes, it works there. Threw me the "File type not supported." error. But still, I want it to work through a validator function in a different file if possible.

Comment: ok so now you have to make your mind either you use it in views or model, i guess the name passing is the model is not getting properly,

Comment: I'm honestly at a loss here. I've seen my original code structure suggested in other answers, and accepted as correct, yet it doesn't work for me.

Comment: why dont use the validation in the view instead of models?

Comment: I can use validation in views. However this does not answer my question as to why the original code is not working. If you edit your answer to put the validation in view, I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: Same problem here. I wanted to use the models validator rather than validating in views. Never got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks right so far. Maybe it's simply a lower/upper case issue?

A more accurate solution might be:

```
import os

def validate_file_type(upload):
    if os.path.splitext(upload.name)[1].lower() != '.gif':
        raise ValidationError('File type not supported.')
```

If it's still not working try to add a break point within the validation method and check the value of `upload.name`.

Comment: I added a print after the function starts, but it doesn't show up on my console.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the form is derived from a simple `Model` class, but in your case you must use `ModelForm` instead.

This way the form knows about the `Document` model, and you can do some fancy operations, like calling the `save` mehond **in the Form object** so save the model instance. Also the `is_valid` method calls all the validations defined in the model, in addition to the validations defined in the Form itself.